# Python GTK. How to continiously show dialog?

Tags: python, gtk

I want to display Dialog over custom Dialog with Listbox. If selected choice in ListBox is wrong, show message and allow to choose the right answer again. I have written this demo code to demonstrate the problem:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from ListBoxRowWithData import ListBoxRowWithData
import shutil
from InterfaceChooserDialog import InterfaceChooserDialog
import netifaces as ni

class InterfaceChooserDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Choose interface", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        self.connect("response", self.on_response)

        wrapper_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        description_label = Gtk.Label("Select one")
        wrapper_box.pack_start(description_label, False, False, 0)
        self.listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
        strings = ["12", "22", "32"]

        for single_string in strings:
            row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
            row.string = single_string
            hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=50)
            row.add(hbox)
            label = Gtk.Label(single_string, xalign=0)
            hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)
            self.listbox.add(row)

        self.selected_interface = self.listbox.get_row_at_index(0)
        self.listbox.select_row(self.selected_interface)
        wrapper_box.pack_start(self.listbox, False, False, 0)
        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(wrapper_box)
        self.show_all()

    def on_response(self, widget, response_id):
        self.selected_one = self.listbox.get_selected_row()

    def get_selected_string(self):
        return self.selected_one.string

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Example")
        self.set_default_size(600, 480)
        dialog = InterfaceChooserDialog(self)
        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK: 
            selected_string = dialog.get_selected_string() 
            print("Selected string", selected_string)
            if selected_string == 12: 
                print("selected")
                dialog.destroy()
            else:
                dialog_wrong = Gtk.MessageDialog(self, 0, Gtk.MessageType.INFO,
                        Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "This is wrong. Select 12")
                dialog_wrong.run()
                dialog_wrong.destroy()


        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            dialog.destroy()


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
```

But it doesn't allow to show the custom Dialog to show multiple times. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Stop destroying the dialog, just hide it.

Comment: @DanD. you mean all dialogs? Inner and outer? Just tried it, the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `Gtk.main()` at the end so the main loop starts to run and the program doesn't quit after the dialog is shown.

If you do that, you probably also want to run `win.show()` in the constructor so the window does not appear after the dialog.